# In git source code, how to know where `run_command` is called? `GIT_TRACE` is not enough

Tags: c, git, trace

If you do `GIT_TRACE=1 git gc`, you'll see below.

```sh
21:43:57.009269 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git gc
21:43:57.015004 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git pack-refs --all --prune
21:43:57.020958 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git pack-refs --all --prune
21:43:57.025294 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git reflog expire --all
21:43:57.030763 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git reflog expire --all
21:43:57.043879 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git repack -d -l -A --unpack-unreachable=2.weeks.ago
21:43:57.050378 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git repack -d -l -A --unpack-unreachable=2.weeks.ago
```

But I want to know where these run_command is called.
In this case, `git pack-refs..` is called from here, and I want to know this place information.

[`builtin/gc.c#maintenance_task_pack_refs()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570/builtin/gc.c#L166-L172)

How can we know this?
Should I use some other tracing tool?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `git grep -n "run_command_v_opt"` in a local cone of [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git/) source code repository

You will see where [`run_command`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570/run-command.c#L1008-L1052) is used.

You also have an online option with [SourceGraph](https://about.sourcegraph.com/) (for public project):

https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=run_command_v_opt+repo:github.com/git/git&patternType=literal

Comment: Ah that is what I did, I just wanted some ways more automatically... thank you anyway.

Comment: do you have any other way like debugging on vscode?

Comment: @eeeeeeeeengo Not that I know of, unless indeed you load the code in an IDE. Maybe https://about.sourcegraph.com/ can help: https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=run_command_v_opt+repo:github.com/git/git&patternType=literal.

Comment: @eeeeeeeeengo I have edited the answer to include that online option.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, but this could be done by grep and VSCode can do that by default inside local editor. I just wanted to know exact process flow, so... I see you are experienced C programmer, so maybe there is no exact answer what I needed. Thank you anyway.